# trouble appending to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to append a div to another using the following function `customizefields`, but i'm not successful. The console returns no errors so I don't know where to go from here?

**javascript**

```
function customizefields(objNames) {
    $('td div').each(function(){
        name = $(this).text();
        if (name.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
            name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" "));
        }
        if (objNames[name]) {
             $('<div/>', {
                  id: 'bio',
                  text: objNames[name].bio
             }).appendTo(this);
        }
    });
}

var namesToChange = {
    'Ben':{'class':'pn_cool','bio':'some text for ben'},
    'Andrew':{'class':'pn_bad','bio':'some text for andrew'}
};

setInterval(function(){customizefields(namesToChange)}, 1000);
```

**html**

```
<tr>
   <td class="stxt2">
      <img src="#" class="pic">
      <div class="dtxt2" title="07/10/12 09:40 PM">40 mins ago</div>
      <b class="nme pn_usr">Andrew</b>: Ut lacus sapien, pretium ut dictum eget, tempus ac nisi.
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="stxt">
      <img src="#" class="pic">
      <div class="dtxt" title="07/10/12 09:30 PM">30 mins ago</div>
      <b class="nme pn_usr">Ben</b>: Cras vitae cursus lectus.
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

**The results I am trying to achieve**

```
    <tr>
       <td class="stxt">
          <img src="#" class="pic">
<div id="bio">TEXT FROM OBJECT WILL GO HERE</div>
          <div class="dtxt" title="07/10/12 09:30 PM">30 mins ago</div>
          <b class="nme pn_usr">Ben</b>: Cras vitae cursus lectus.
       </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: Do some simple debugging. If the elements is not append it means that either the function is not invoked or `if (objNames[name])` is `false`. So lets have a look which values `name` has: It will be `30` and `40` respectively (http://jsfiddle.net/9eDXS/) and both are not properties in your `namesToChange` object. Seems like you want to get the text from the `b` element, not the `div` element.

Comment: @Felix Kling if i change to `$('td b')` it places the div inside the `<b>` tag. any idea how i can make it go on the outside?

Comment: You can use DOM traversal methods to get the element you want to append the new element to: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/. Or you use functions like `.after` or `.before`: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/. Take your time and browser through the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you should be looking at the textual content of the sibling `b` tag, not, as currently, the `div` tag.

Currently, for example, the value of your `name` var (which, by the way, is global) would be '40' and, for the next iteration, '30'.

Presumably you meant

```
$('td div').each(function() {
    name = $(this).next('b').text();
    //more code...
```

Comment: here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/9eDXS/3/ is there anyway to make it display one time. it constantly repeats but also keep the `setInterval` intact?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the JQuery api
    .before or .prepend